# missing reverse resolution in ssh connection

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, pam

i'm having an issue during the connection via ssh from a windows server to a linux server RH4 using ssh-key pair authentication because the reverse resolution doesn't run here although it runs using nslookup IP_ADDRESS. 
In /home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys of the server I specified the From option with the hostname.

Here you are the related row in secure log in which should be there the HOSTNAME instead the IP_ADDRESS:

```
 debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "IP_ADDRESS"
```

This one causes the failure:

```
Authentication tried for USER with correct key but not from a permitted host (host=IP_ADDRESS, ip=::ffff:IP_ADDRESS).
```

I already set

```
UseDNS yes
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, but nothing change.
Do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: Can you resolve the hostname you added to your authorized_keys from that RH4 server?  I.e. do  `nslookup your-from-hostname` rather than `nslookup IP_ADDRESS`

Comment: @HBruijn, yes, it runs in both directions